# Add an order note to customers when they approve their orders in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, *[Allow customer to change order status in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066590/allow-customer-to-change-order-status-in-woocommerce/63067443#63067443)* answer to my previous question, allows the customer to approve (complete) orders in "My Account" page, but I don't know how to add a note automatically, so when the Customer approves an order (order status is changed to completed), I want to automatically add a note for customer.

Is it possible to add a Note when customer approve an order and status is changed to "completed"?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Note on admin orders pages, note with Blue Background  "Notes to the customer". so Customers can view them by viewing an order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an order note for the customer, replace the following code line:

```
        // Change order status to "completed"
        $order->update_status( 'completed', __('Approved by the customer', 'woocommerce') ) ;
```

by:

```
        // Add an order note for the customer (blue background note in admin orders)
        $order->add_order_note( __('You have approved this order on', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . date_i18n( 'F j, Y' ), true );

        // Change order status to "completed"
        $order->update_status( 'completed', __('Approved by the customer', 'woocommerce') ) ;
```

**WooCommerce Documentation:** [`WC_Order` method `add_order_note()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_add_order_note)

Comment: thank for your answer, i was test but that code is adding customer order note , like addisional note in Checkout Page ? what i meant is adding Note to Customer in Admin orders Page ,like this Documentation [Order Note](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-orders/#section-15)

Comment: @JulioEnsutias I have updated my answer with explanations…

Comment: yes it is, but method update_status() adding note with 'purple' background, what i want is adding note with 'blue' background (note to customer) so i can show that note with calling function get_customer_order_notes() , is is possible to change note type ?

Comment: Ok I have catch it… found … I have updated my answer.